# Xamarin.form ListView fill space horizontally then jump to the next row

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to display a list of items having multiple rows of items and scrolling vertically.

As an example what i really want to accomplish is display a list of buttons, if horizontally there is enough space for 3 buttons and i want to display 12 then id like to have 4 rows of 3 buttons, if there is not enough space for the 4 rows then it should be vertically scrollable.

Is there a way to do it? As i have not found a solution with ListView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Xamarin.Forms package https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/tree/master/FlowListView

It provides a "GridView" style like this:

[image: GridView]